# true or false GCD PROBLEM

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let a be an integer.  Then the greatest common divisor of a and 0 is the absolute value of a?

My thoughts: true.  Because everything divides zero whatever divides a (whether is be positive or negative) the absolute value of a would divide both of them.  Right logic here?

Comment: Note that for the sake of completeness you should say that $a$ is a non zero integer.

Comment: the question does not state a is non-zero though.... so would that make the statement false? saying it is just an integer might not be saying enough. It is what I was thinking just now

Comment: I would rather say that the question is ill-posed. gcd (0,0) is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

True. Generally if $\,a\mid b\,$ then $\,d\mid a,b\iff d\mid a,\,$ so $\,\gcd\{a,b\} = \gcd\{a\} = a.\,$ In the same manner, it follows that any gcd argument that is a multiple of another may be deleted. In turn, this is a special case of the fact that $\,\gcd\{a,a_1,a_2,\ldots\} = \gcd\{a,\bar a_1,\bar a_2,\ldots\}\ $ if $\ a_i \equiv \bar a_i\pmod a,\ $ which is the key modular reduction step used in the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd.

Answer (score 0):

True, since any number is a divisor of 0.